# Check if SPAlert is set to a Folder in a List

Tags: list, alert

I have an SPAlert and want to check if it is set for a folder in a list.

```
private static bool IsSetToFolder(SPAlert alert) 
{
   //How do I do that
}
```

Is there any way to do that in C#?

Comment: how do you wanna check that? By Powershell, JS, C#? From a webpart, console app? For which users?

Comment: I would like to do it with C#. I have all SPAlerts for the current user of a siteCollection. Now I want to check if the SPAlert is set to a folder in a list or not. I'm able to check if it is set to a List / ListItem / Document / DocumentLibrary. Now I have problems to check wether it is set to a folder...

Comment: you have to work with the folder as an item

Answer (score 1):

```
private static bool IsSetToFolder(SPAlert alert)
{
    SPListItem item = alert.Item;
    if (item != null)
    {
        if (item.FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder)
        {
            // Alert is set to Folder
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea thanks! But I can't do that, because the Item is null. Only the list is set.

Comment: Then that means Alert is set on a List not on items

Comment: That's the problem. When you set an alert on an item in a list the item and the list are set. But when you set it to a folder or a list only the list is set and the item is null.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the Filterpath Property of SPAlert is only set, when the alert is set to a folder:

```
private static bool IsSetToFolder(SPAlert alert)
{
    //For each folder a filterpath is set
    string filterpath = alert.Properties["Filterpath"] as string;

    if (alert.Item == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(filterpath)) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Check if filterpath applies to a folder in the list of alert
    List<SPListItem> list = alert.List.Folders.Cast<SPListItem>()
      .Where(folder => filterpath.TrimEnd('/').EndsWith(folder.Url.TrimEnd('/')) ).ToList();

    if (list.Count == 1)
    {
        if (list[0].FileSystemObjectType == SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```